# Two implementations for List Monad bind in the literature: why are they equivalent?

Tags: haskell

Reading the Monad chapter in "Programming in Haskell" 2nd ed. from Graham Hutton, I found this example on page 167 to illustrate the behaviour of the List Monad:

```
> pairs [1,2] [3,4]
[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

With pairs defined like this:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
pairs xs ys = do x <- xs
                 y <- ys
                 return (x,y)
```

And this implementation of bind:

```
instance Monad [] where
   -- (>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
   xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
```

I tried to understand with pencil and paper how the example worked out, but didn't get it.

Then I found, that in other books the bind operation is defined differently:

```
...
   xs >>= f = concat (fmap f xs)
```

With this definition I understand why the example works.
But the first definition is the one I found on hackage in the prelude, so I trust its correct.

**My question**:

- Can anybody explain why the first definition is equivalent to the second?          (Where does the concat-stuff happen in the first one?)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are just syntactic sugar. Basically, `[f x y | x<-l, y<-m]` is sugar for

```
concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> return $ f x y) m) l
```

or equivalently

```
concat $ fmap (\x -> concat $ fmap (\y -> return $ f x y) m) l
```

thus the two implementations are indeed equivalent *by definition*.

Anyway you can of course manually evaluate the example from the comprehension-based definition, using “intuitive set comprehension” evaluation:

```
pairs [1,2] [3,4]
 ≡ do { x <- [1,2]; y <- [3,4]; return (x,y) }
 ≡ [1,2] >>= \x -> [3,4] >>= \y -> return (x,y)
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- (\ξ -> [3,4] >>= \y -> return (ξ,y)) x]
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- ([3,4] >>= \y -> return (x,y))]
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- [q | y<-[3,4], q <- (\υ -> return (x,υ)) y]]
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- [q | y<-[3,4], q <- return (x,y)]]
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- [q | y<-[3,4], q <- [(x,y)]]]
 ≡ [p | x<-[1,2], p <- [(x,3), (x,4)]]
 ≡ [(1,3), (1,4)] ++ [(2,3), (2,4)]
 ≡ [(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)]
```

Comment: thx a lot ... I have to chew that now slowly :-) But right now I reckognized that my understanding of list comprehension was much too naive: its quite a beast.

Answer (score 0):

`[y | x <- xs, y <- f x]` takes all the `x`s in `xs` one-by-one and

1. apply `f` to them, which is a monadic action `a -> [a]`, thus the result  is a list of values (`[a]`)
2. the comprehension proceeds to address each `y` in `f x` one-by-one
3. each `y` is sent to the output list

this is equivalent to first mapping `f` over each of the elements of the input list, resulting in a list of nested lists, that are then concatenated. Notice that `fmap` is `map` for lists, and you could use `concatMap f xs` as the definition of `xs >>= f`.

Comment: Thank you ... now I learned that there is an implicit concat in list comprehensions.

Comment: Note that list comprehensions are a special case of monad comprehensions, which are a special syntax for do-notation, which is special syntax for `>>=`, which uses `join` under the hood. The "implicit concat" is more generally the monadic `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`.

Comment: Yes, but explaining `>>=` implemented in terms of comprehension and explaining that in terms of `do`-notation and that in terms of `>>=` is a bit cyclic.

Comment: @Lazersmoke Indeed -- that `(>>= f) = join . fmap f` is relevant here. To avoid confusion, it is also worth mentioning that, as things stand, `(>>=)` doesn't *literally* use `join` under the hood (though it would of course be possible to implement it that way). `join x` is currently defined as `x >>= id`.

Comment: @duplode to clarify, I meant "under the hood" in the sense that `join` is the theoretical fundamental operation on monads, and that `>>=` is just a nice and equivalent way to define it (using the identity `join = (>>= id)`)

Comment: ( @Lazersmoke Yup -- it's just that "under the hood" initially made me think more of "in letter" than of "in spirit".)